# if (isset()) statement is causing screen to be blank

Tags: php

Hey i create a table of words and cut out values associated with the words in the table.  I need to have it so when i click on a word it prints out the cut out information of the word, which is ultimately information associated with the word.  Problem is that when i add in my isset statement and refresh the page it just makes a blank screen

Here is my full code

```
    <html>
<body>
<script>

  function wordCheck(chosenOne) {
     window.location="http://granite.sru.edu/~jaw1005/word.php?chosenOne=\"" + chosenOne + "\""

  }
</script>
<center>
<table id="test" border="1">
<?

$f="/homes/ddailey/public_html/threefull";
$o=file($f);
$rn=count($o);


for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
 print "<tr>";

    for ($g=0;$g<6;$g++){

      $lol=rand(1, $rn);
      $word= explode(" ", ltrim( $o[$lol], ' 0123456789'));
      $fullword = str_replace("\n", "&nbsp;", $o[$lol]);
      print "<td onClick='wordCheck(\"".$fullword."\")'>".ucfirst($word[0])."</td>";

   }
 print "</tr>";

}

if(isset($chosenOne)){
  $realWord=str_replace('"', "", $chosenOne);
  $wordSplit = explode(" ", $realWord);
  print ucfirst($wordSplit[2])."'s part of speech is: ".$wordSplit[3].", while its               frequency is:".$wordSplit[0];

?>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Through debugging i have decided this is the part of code that is cause problems

```
   if(isset($chosenOne)){
      $realWord=str_replace('"', "", $chosenOne);
      $wordSplit = explode(" ", $realWord);
      print ucfirst($wordSplit[2])."'s part of speech is: ".$wordSplit[3].", while its               frequency is:".$wordSplit[0];
```

Here is a link to the page http://granite.sru.edu/~jaw1005/word.php

Comment: You need to store that word inside COOKIE and then you can use isset on that created COOKIE.

Comment: where is the closing bracket of if condition?

Comment: Yes so `$chosenOne` is not set anywhere in your code. Set it

Comment: i think you should be using `(if(isset($_GET["chosenOne"]))` to check

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the braces **`}`**

```
if(isset($chosenOne)){
  $realWord=str_replace('"', "", $chosenOne);
  $wordSplit = explode(" ", $realWord);
  print ucfirst($wordSplit[2])."'s part of speech is: ".$wordSplit[3].", while its               frequency is:".$wordSplit[0];
}//<--- here
?>
```